# Pycharm install error while trying to install the cv2 package

Tags: python, pycharm, opencv

I tried to install the package `cv2` on my pycharm, but I get an install error:

> collecting cv2
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for cv2 You are using pip
>   version 9.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available. You should
>   consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Installation of this package through the terminal succeed (I'm using python 3.6) but the package doesn't work on pycharm (the command line is `pip3 install opencv-python`).

Thanks for helping

Comment: Maybe pycharm is using virtualenv or some other env and terminal is using global version of python?

Comment: Also it happens sometimes in $Path you can have pip from one python installation eg. 2.7 and python from 3.x

Comment: thanks. not using virtualenv :/

Comment: you can report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ if you think it's a bug.